# Add disabled selected option in select menu via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

We have a select menu that is being populated via data- attributes and a knockout.js array. I'm not so familiar with jQuery as well, keep this in mind.

How could I add an option via jQuery that is the first selected one and it's disabled as well. Basically, it's being used as a placeholder. I know how to do this via HTML, but not in this way. Here is the HTML that is being used:

`<select id="delemilter" data-bind="options: delimiterList, value: delimiterSelectedValue, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'name', enable: true"></select>`

In other select menus, one of our developers used this line of jQuery. Seems to be some knockout API stuff. Looks like an observable array:

`self.selectMenuID.push({ value: 'Placeholder Text', key: 0, data: 0, disabled: true });`

Can't figure out how to reuse this again... Hopefully this is enough information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
$('#delemilter').prepend('<option disabled="disabled">My disabled Option</option>');
```

Remember to specify other attributes in our option's html as required.

Here is a JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/ask9L71h/

Comment: Awesome thank you! Now I have to figure out why it's still selecting the second option (originally first) even though I have a `selected` attribute on the `.prepend`. Probably will need the developers help. But this did work, just not completely for my specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

I find this way much more elegant & readable:

```js
$("select").append($("<option>", {
    value: "foo",
    text: "bar"
}).prop("disabled", true));
```